# How to get only a response boolean in curl php

Tags: php, curl

I have the following code

```
$handle = curl_int();
$i = '123456';
curl_setopt_array(
    $handle, 
    array(
        CURLOPT_URL =>'localhost/unnamed/loginpage.php',
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "uname=birat&pword=$i",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    )
);

$response = curl_exec($handle);

//This if statement doesnot work
if($response == 1) {
    echo 'Password is '. $i;
}

}
curl_close($handle);
```

The problem is that I always get the whole html page instead of just '1' or '0' indicating me that the username and password matches. Also the last if statement does not work. If i don't use this if statement, I get the good result i.e '1' at the top and the html data of the page below it. I don't want that html data. I just want '1' or '0' and I want this if clause to work. What do I do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to check the http code as well. This might help you.

```
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($handle,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ($httpcode == '200')
{
    //logged in
}
else
{
    //not logged in
}
```

In most cases HTTP code 200 is a valid authentication.

Comment: It worked. But still don't know if the page is downloaded and ignored or the page is not downloaded at all

Comment: Try removing this line `$response = curl_exec($handle);`. This is the one that gets the page.

Comment: I removed it and now $httpcode = '200' is valid for all the data rather than just specific password.

Comment: Make sure you are using `==` in your if, not just `=`

Answer (score 0):

CUrl just performing requests for you and, in your case, returns contents of target page. You need to output only `1` or `0` on target page and check like this:

```
if ( trim($result)=='1' ) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: After reading your answer, I could say you did not even read his question.

Comment: @TraianTatic I could say this about you too :) As I understood, OP receives whole HTML of target page with "1" or "0" on it somewhere (`CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` is TRUE) and he needs only this number instead of whole page.

Comment: Yes I could do that but I don't want it to download the whole page. I just want it to have the response '1' or '0', not the whole page.

Comment: He gets the whole HTML, as expected, but he just wants to know if his auth succeded or not. If the curl works without errors, it will always return 1.

Comment: @TraianTatic `curl_exec()` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` only when `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` is `FALSE`. Please, refer to documentation on `curl_exec()`. So, in your case OP needs to response with appropriate HTTP status code, and in my case he would have to cut output to just a number somehow.

Comment: _Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure._

Comment: @TraianTatic And now you can re-read my messages and realize that I am pointing to this. Anyways, this is really not good to discuss these things in comments.